# How can I open new page in wordpress plugin on anchor tag click?

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a simple plugin for learning purpose and I'm struck on a very basic point. I have page of my plugin in admin panel and in that page I have list of pages. I want when I click on page title it should open in a new page with information about that specific page. Following is the code I tried but anchor tag doesnot open new page but it give "Page not found error".

```
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ($pages as $key => $pagesResult) {
echo '<a href="displayComments.php?pageId=' .$pagesResult->ID .'" target="_blank">' . $pagesResult->post_title . '<a><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link is not correct. It should be something like:

```
 admin.php?page=Comments+Control&pageId=
```

Comment: I tried your code with little correction(admin.php?page=displayComments.php&pageId=21) but got following error:

You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Comment: @UmairMalik When you are opening your plugin page what url is it showing?

Comment: Following is the link of plugin page where anchor tag is displayed:

http://localhost/plugins_test/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Comments+Control

Following is the URL when I click on the anchor tag:
http://localhost/plugins_test/wp-admin/admin.php?page=displayComments.php&pageId=21

Comment: @UmairMalik I have updated my answer try this new link

Comment: it didn't worked either. I think we have to use hooks or something to create pages in plugin but don't know how to do this.

Comment: @UmairMalik what do you mean by didnt work? This is how its done you need to figure out the correct url

Comment: i tried your code but It gives page not found error. displayComment.php is the file I want to run when I click on anchor tag. I'm also passing page id as parameter in URL.